# Don't render Image when Image.Source is empty

Tags: xaml, uwp

In the ListView, I need to show some images and text, only display the text when the `Image.Source` is empty. How to do?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.News}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="home:NormalNews">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
                <Image Source="{x:Bind Thumbnail}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel Data Source like:

```
News.Add(new NormalNews{ Title = "title1", Thumbnail = "http://a.com/test.jpg" });
News.Add(new NormalNews{ Title = "title2", Thumbnail = "" });
```

When I tried to run  this page, it stopped running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this using xaml converters.

Add a converter and define a key for it in your page.

In XAML page

```xml
<converter:ImageUriConverter x:Key="ImageUriConvert"/>
```

In your list

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail,Converter={StaticResource ImageUriConvert}}"/>
```

Converter class code

```cs
class ImageUriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == string.Empty)
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString()));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are populating the ViewModel object, do this:

```
   ViewModel.News.Add(new NormalNews{
Thumbnail=(the Thumbnail source which you will be using),
Title=(the Thumbnail source which you will be using)==""?"Your Title":""});
```

This will set your Title to the specified string when your Thumbnail source is empty.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cannot change title,When the `Image.Source` is empty, only render `TextBlock`, not render `Image`

Comment: News.Add(new NormalNews{ Title = "title1", Thumbnail = "http://a.com/test.jpg" });
News.Add(new NormalNews{ Title = "title2", Thumbnail = "" });        any specific error as to why this code stopped running ??

Comment: Stopped in App.g.i.cs `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`, I guess it was `Image.Soucre=""`